# How to set session storage in daterangepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, session-storage, daterangepicker

I need to use session to keep the user's selection. (In case the date range which user has picked turns back to default when the data refresh).

Here is my daterangepicker code. Please help me on how to set the session storage of 'start' date and 'end' date and how to retrieve them from session storage. Thanks in advance.

```
    var start = moment();
    var end = moment();

    $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
    startDate: start,
    endDate: end,
    ranges: {
    'Today': [moment(), moment()],
    'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
    'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
    'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
    'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
    'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
    }
}, cb);


function cb(start, end) {
    $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('DD MMMM YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('DD MMMM YYYY'));      
}

cb(start, end);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this script to get and set your session data

```
// Store
sessionStorage.setItem("start", "Smith");
// Retrieve
let startDate = sessionStorage.getItem("start");
```